# Compile Vim with GTK2 in Cygwin

Tags: user-interface, vim, compilation, gtk, cygwin

I am trying to compile Vim on Cygwin, for Ruby and Python scripting support.

`vim.exe` --which is the terminal vim- compiles and runs fine, but `gvim.exe` does not.  The problem is in the GTK+ 2 libraries, but I have them installed --from setup.exe of cygwin. I tried with higher and lower versions of GTK also.

Here is the relevant part from configure script. Any ideas are welcomed...

```
checking --enable-gui argument... GTK+ 2.x GUI support
checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled
checking for GTK - version >= 2.2.0... no
checking X11/SM/SMlib.h usability... yes
checking X11/SM/SMlib.h presence... yes
checking for X11/SM/SMlib.h... yes
checking X11/xpm.h usability... yes
checking X11/xpm.h presence... yes
checking for X11/xpm.h... yes
checking X11/Sunkeysym.h usability... yes
checking X11/Sunkeysym.h presence... yes
checking for X11/Sunkeysym.h... yes
checking for XIMText in X11/Xlib.h... yes
no GUI selected; xim has been disabled
```

Comment: what result of `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` ?

Comment: can you post the your setups? including which package you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install all the -devel packages required, including

   - gtk2
   - glib2
   - pangoo
   - atk
   - cairo
   - pixman
   - x11
   - libXt-devel
2. Install `gcc4` cygwin package (solves `libffi` problem)
3. Run

   `./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-multibyte --enable-pythoninterp --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-rubyinterp --disable-gtktest`

   gtktest has problems on cygwin, I didn't dig for the reasons
4. `make && make install`

Comment: just wanted to make a note for people in need: from a fresh cygwin install all you need is these

make, libncurses-devel, pkg-config and lib*-devel where * is for the list above,